# SQL, how to automatically assign new row to a relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I created 2 tables and linked their ids. Now whenever I delete a record from the main table, it gets deleted from the related table too. But whenever I create a new row in the main table, it doesn't create a new one for the linked table. How can I do that?

Comment: What you want is called triggers. However, it seems likely to me what either your second table is superfluous or a trigger cannot create a row in your second table automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may do this via an after insert trigger, which might look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_follow_up
ON maintbl
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO followuptbl
-- logic for the insert
END
GO
```

The trigger would fire after every insert on the main table, and would insert a record into the follow up table, using some logic, which you may fill in.